# Is there an up to date .net sdk or library?

Tags: sdk, library, c-sharp

Some companies want to interact with prebuilt c# code. Is there a more high level interface than writing lots of p-invokes?

Comment: I suppose you've probably seen this one https://github.com/ajuna-network/SubstrateNetApi and are looking for something more up-to-date and refined? I'd like to see that too

Comment: Yes, there's also https://github.com/usetech-llc/polkadot_api_dotnet but both have not been updated in a while. I suspect upgrading to making the most use of the metadata might be non-trivial but extremely worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a .NET library that is dynamically generated from your node's metadata. The current name is a little bit misleading as it is a generic toolchain that works for all substrate-based nodes and is not specific to a project.

Substrate C# Toolchain that generates a NET API and more https://github.com/ajuna-network/Ajuna.SDK

And has a lot of tutorials and was showcased at the Sub0 in Lisabon.
[Ajuna sub0 Talk: Substrate .NET Toolchain & Unity](https://github.com/ajuna-network/ajuna-sub0)

And can also be used for [Unity](https://unity.com/) or [Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0)
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5565/707

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is currently no "production-grade" .NET library which will dynamically generate API code from the chain metadata.

Fortunately there seems to be work happening on it. There is now [Ajuna.NetApi](https://github.com/ajuna-network/Ajuna.NetApi) (which is a fork/rewrite of [SubstrateNetApi](https://github.com/ajuna-network/SubstrateNetApi)), and it focuses on generating API code from chain metadata. It seems to still be in development and documentation is scarce. I don't have any experience with any of these libraries so can't personally vouch for them.